# Create graphic and save it as Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, picturebox

I have two questions:

1) I have a `PictureBox` and its Dock is set to Fill. When I resize the `Form` I cannot create a Graphic on the part of the `PictureBox` that is extended. What is the problem?

2) I want to convert the Graphic that is created on the `PictureBox` to `Bitmap` and save it as
*.JPG or *.bmp. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the [handle device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z5820hw.aspx)  to get the bitmap out of  the picture box

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();          
Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(g.GetHdc());
bitMap.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

or even better, if the pictureBox does`nt modify the image,  you can directly get the image from the pictureBox control

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save("path", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, works fine for me...

```
    private void SaveControlImage(Control ctr)
    {
        try
        {
            var imagePath = @"C:\Image.png";

            Image bmp = new Bitmap(ctr.Width, ctr.Height);
            var gg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            var rect = ctr.RectangleToScreen(ctr.ClientRectangle);
            gg.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, ctr.Size);

            bmp.Save(imagePath);
            Process.Start(imagePath);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this before, unfortunately the image you are saving is then restricted to the size of the control itself. So if you are using zoom to fit a huge image into a control, when you export the image it will be the rendered size and not its actual size.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your description is very vague. Do you get an exception? Does it display wrong results? What is happening?

2) You need to get the Image from the PictureBox and use its [Save method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: 1) I dont get any Eception and it doesnt display wrong result just Grafhic doesnt creat.

Comment: Please try to describe this in more detail... it is really hard to understand what is happening. How do you know it is not created? Is this only if you set Dock to Fill?

Comment: You know a PictureBox has an MouseClick event. when i click on the PictureBox i want to draw a rectangle on PictureBox. it is work but when i resize Form to larger beacaus the Dock of PictureBox is Fill it become lrger like Form. after resize i cannot create Grafhic on the part that became larger ..... I hope you understood my problem

Comment: I can explain more: when a Graphics object is created from a control like PictureBox or Panel, the graphics drawn on it are unstable: the Paint event of the control will clear repainted area. for example if you try to show a little dialog on the Control that have Graphics object, after dialog is closed, it's area will be cleared on the Control. another example: move your window into edges of screen, so half of your window falls out of screen view--> now set window to normal, you can't see drawed graphics on the missplaced half...

Answer (score 0):

When the Picturebox gets resized to fill the form, it seems it's Image property stays the same.

So what you need to do is handle the PictureBox.OnSizeChanged Event, and then use the following code to resize the image:

```
private void pictureBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((pictureBox1.Image != null))
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Size);
    }
}
```

To save the image use:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: -1: the problem is not related to the Image of PictureBox. He try to draw something stable on a control (PictureBox, Panle or even Form itself).