# Convert BMP file to PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

I want to convert a file format BMP to PDF in Visual Studio using Visual Basic technology and I use the PDFsharp library to do this.
I recieved the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in PdfSharp-wpf.dll
>
> Additional information: The file 'E:...\bin\Debug-1493104802' does not exist.

I copied the whole contents of form to .bmp and it runs correctly. You can see my code:

```
Call SendMessage(TableLayoutPanel2.Handle, WM_PRINT, hdc, _ EDrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN Or _ EDrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT Or _ EDrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT Or _ EDrawingOptions.PRF_OWNED)

myGraphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc)

Dim doc As New PdfDocument()
doc.Pages.Add(New PdfPage())
Dim xgr As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages(0))
Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromFile(myGraphics.GetHdc)

xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0)
doc.Save("E:\out.pdf")
doc.Close()


'  myBmp.Save("E:\out.bmp")

myGraphics.Dispose()
myGraphics = Nothing

myBmp = Nothing
```

Comment: Make sure the file `E:...\bin\Debug-1493104802` exists. If you want a real answer you'll need to show your code.

Comment: I don't think you can convert it, but you definitely can paint the bmp to a new `PdfDocument` using the `XGraphics` object.

Comment: Thanks for ur answers . I would to  copie it in a PdfDocument . I dnt find a problem in code . my problem in the library PdfSharp

Comment: Maybe just ".bmp" missing from the filename. Maybe there is more wrong, assuming that "bin\Debug" is a folder.

Comment: Show your code. We would have a better time helping you if we could see _how_ you were using PdfSharp. Looking at the error, the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I copied the whole contents of form to .bmp and it run correctly . u can see my codes :

Comment: You should edit your question to add code, not add it as an answer. If your code works and you're _really sure_ then look at the error and check the file exists.

Comment: You should take a moment to read [Ask], take the [Tour] and perhaps visit the [help].  You have only 1 upvoted question with 3 heavily downvoted ones.  If it hasnt happened already, you are probably close to being banned from asking or throttled.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code it looks like you are generating an image using myGraphics, if that is the case you may want to save this to a tempfile, load it into the pdf and then you can delete it after you save the pdf.

Use the information on the following link to save the file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2881188/7436406

Comment: Yes that's all what I'am doing and really I don't know what should I do now to resolve it

Comment: @AliLatrach Provide an MCVE, not just a code fragment. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet:

```
Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromFile(myGraphics.GetHdc)
```

You need a file name, but you pass an HDC? Great.
Maybe the compiler implicitly calls ToString() to make this compile. But there is no file.

Save the image to a Stream and then call `XImage.FromStream` to get that image in PDFsharp.